# Does anyone know how to do this effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve the effect from these photos in Photoshop?  I have been trying many different things, but I am not even coming close...

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

Comment: What is the effect?

Comment: Action, filter etc...

Comment: I mean, what you want to do to your image?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same with a couple of my photos like what is shown above. The photos are for a new website.

Comment: Try https://www.google.com/nikcollection/ . It is simple to use and you can make a lot of effects.

Comment: Is still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Please try to describe in words what you want to do, preferably with a starting image. The 'effect' you are trying to achieve might as well be 'add an Apple device and a bearded hipster' :)

Comment: And hello Dimitri, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: First you dress your set & your models in the colour-pallet you wish to emphasise, then you light it hard from one side & fill soft from the other. Unless you start from there, photoshop is unlikely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell what has been done with these images, and to what extent, especially when there is no original image to compare it against.  Also the original lighting in the photograph plays its part. Even editing a similar image in the same way might not result in the same look if the lighting is significantly different.

However, you could apply a curves adjustment to get a similar effect. Here I lifted the shadows on the RGB curve, and similarly with the shadow end of the blue curve, and adjusted the red and green curves to add some warmth to the image.

[image]

Comment: Hi Billy. Can I draw your attention to [this discussion](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/what-to-do-with-tutorial-requests-part-ii) on meta? We are trying to decrease the amount of lazy 'tutorial-on-demand' questions on the site, and one of the early signs is that answering them isn't a good idea. I'd appreciate your input on the matter. Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent Do you want me to delete this answer?

Comment: No. At least, not yet, depending on the outcome of the discussion. I mainly wanted to draw your attention to the discussion, and this is the first answer on a TOD-question of yours that I could find.